# how to populate data in roles_users table Using devise in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am just learning using devise in rails following ryan bates video tutorial

it works fine for me .

but now i need to add roles in my application to apply role based condition in cancan integration

my models 1 : user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  def role?(role)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
  end
end
```

my model 2 : role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

my user migration file

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

my role migration file

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

my join table migration file

```
class UsersHaveAndBelongToManyRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :roles_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :role, :user
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :roles_users
  end
end
```

now when i create a user , i want my role to be attached with the user and also the join table should have the entry ,

how can i do it ??

Comment: Please add `has_and_belongs_to_many :roles` in User model

Comment: @RajaD : well thats just a typo i will edit it , but please tell me if i need to write anything in the controller or view page , by the way , i am simply calling devise :users/sign_up , the sign up page comes but no roles check box or selection option, how can I do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails creates the join table entry automatically. You can set roles to users in many different ways. Here are some examples:

```
 @user << Role.find_by_name('admin') # Adds the admin role to the users roles and save
 @user.roles.create(:name => 'admin') # Creates a new role and add to the the user
 @user.role_ids = [1,2,3] # Adds the roles with id 1, 2 and 3 and delete all others
 @user.roles = [Role.find_by_name('admin'), Role.find_by_name('superuser')] # Adds admin and superuser roles and delete all others
```

You can see all available options here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference

This means that if you want to have a default role, when creating new users, could you do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  before_create :set_default_role

  private
  def set_default_role
    # Add the default role if no roles is set
    self.roles << Role.find_by_name('default') if roles.empty?
  end
end
```

You can also read more about the subject here: http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/

Comment: whats wrong with the line <%= collection_select(:user,:roles,Role.all,:id,:name) %> , in the view page , says , cant find each method for string '2' which is the id of the role selected

Comment: Can see any problems with that, seems good... Can you maybe add it to your question or create a new, with some more context?